# "Київ" англійською

Tags: transliteration

Згідно української транслітерації, Київ англійською пишеться `Kyiv`. Буквосполучення `yi` важко вимовляти іноземцям, адже в них немає звуку `и`. Тому дуже часто на закордонних сайтах помилково пишуть стару російську версію транслітерації `Kiev`. Оскільки російською мовою Київ дійсно вимовляється *Кієв*, а в Україні живе багато російськомовних людей, то іноземці часто переймають невірне написання та вимову `Kiev`.

Як переконливо пояснити іноземцям, що слід писати `Kyiv` і чому багато самих українців пишуть `Kiev`? Погодьтеся, це для них не дуже очевидно.

Comment: Питання цікаве, але хіба це стосується української мови? Адже в українській мові однозначно — «Київ». Це вже питання про англійську: за якими принципами вони запозичують, наскільки та і яких саме сферах в них поширені варіанти Kiev і Kyiv та чому вони не змінюють на Kyiv остаточно.

Comment: Але цікаво, які саме аргументи наводити при цьому. Адже не всі іноземці живуть у двомовній країні після розпаду імперії. Я спілкувався з німцями та американцями. Вони взагалі не розуміють, чому в нас тут така заплутана ситуація з мовою, друкованими виданнями, озвученням фільмів, Церквою. У них такого просто немає.

Comment: Інколи вживають й варіант з Kyyiv, я ж методично пояснюю, що правильно вживати саме український варіант, а вживання застарілого "Kiev" може бути шкідливим для здоров’я

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Коректно писати `Kyiv`, а не `Kiev`.**

Англійська Вікіпедія містить сторінку [Kiev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev) з приміткою "This article is about the capital of Ukraine. For other uses, see Kiev (disambiguation).". При переході на сторінку [Kyiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv) сторінка перенаправляється на вже згадану сторінку Kiev (хороша новина в тому, що перенаправлення налаштоване, погана - в тому, що має бути навпаки).
[**Оновлено вересень 2020:**](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/8) сторінка [Kyiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv) стала основною, а [Kiev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev) стала сторінкою перенаправлення.

> Kiev (/ˈkiːɛf, -ɛv/) or Kyiv (Ukrainian: Київ [ˈkɪjiu̯] ( listen);
> Russian: Киев [ˈkʲiɪf]) is the capital...

Нижче в тексті статті написано наступне:

> Currently, Kiev is the traditional and most commonly used English name
> for the city (1), but in 1995 the Ukrainian government adopted Kyiv as
> the mandatory romanization for use in legislative and official acts.
> (2)
>
> Kyiv ([ˈkɪjiw]) is the romanized version of the name of the city used
> in modern Ukrainian. Following independence in 1991, the Ukrainian
> government introduced the [national rules for transliteration of
> geographic names from Ukrainian into English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Ukrainian). According to the rules,
> the Ukrainian Київ transliterates into Kyiv. This has established the
> use of the spelling Kyiv in all official documents issued by the
> governmental authorities since October 1995. The spelling is used by
> the United Nations, all English-speaking foreign diplomatic missions,
> several international organizations, [Encarta encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encarta), and by some
> media in Ukraine. In October 2006, the United States federal
> government changed its official spelling of the city name to Kyiv,
> upon the recommendation of the US Board of Geographic Names. The
> British government has also started using Kyiv. The alternate
> romanizations Kyyiv (BGN/PCGN transliteration) and Kyjiv (scholarly)
> are also in use in English-language atlases. Most major
> English-language news sources like the BBC, The Economist, and the New
> York Times continue to prefer Kiev.
>
> (1)  In 2008, the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) included 19
> quotations with 'Kiev' and none with any other spelling. This spelling
> is also given by [Britannica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica) and [Columbia Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia_Encyclopedia).
>
> (2) ["Resolution of the Ukrainian commission for legal terminology No.
> 5"](http://www.uazone.net/Kiev_Kyiv.html). Ukrainian Commission for Legal Terminology. Retrieved 15 March
> 2011.

Деякі думки в захист написання Kiev замість Kyiv (в квадратних дужках - мої коментарі):

> Насправді, іншим країнам абсолютно не важливо, як [офіційний] Київ хоче, щоб його писали на інших мовах - у кожної мови власна фонетика і
> деякі звуки можуть бути не типовими і не вимовлятись нормально. Тому
> цілком природньо адаптувати назви так, щоб людям було зручно і щоб
> інші люди могли зрозуміти, про що йде мова.
>
> В Англії до цих пір всюди пишуть Kiev. Тому що в англійській мові немає звуку `И`. Так само, як вони не збираються вчити німецькі звуки
> в назвах німецьких міст. Кельн у них вимовляється Cologne (Колон),
> Мюнхен - Munich (Мюніх). По-китайськи, Київ буде 基輔 (Jīfǔ або ціфу).
> Що б далеко не ходити, українською або російською деякі європейські
> міста взагалі звучать по іншому. Хорошим прикладом буде Відень (Wien)
> [та Пекін]. [(c)](http://ukdimat.blogspot.com/2010/05/kiev-kyiv.html)

Така проблема не лише у Києва, але й у багатьох країн та міст. Деякі приклади зібрані в статті [List of European regions with alternative names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_regions_with_alternative_names).

Відгук українця, що працює в Європі (звісно, по одному відгуку важко говорити про істину в останній інстанції, проте, на мій погляд, ця думка заслуговує уваги):

> I’m afraid changing the name right now will be confusing for our
> international community, who:
>
> 1. won’t be able to read/pronounce it properly 2) won’t be able to
>    recognize where the city is located
>
> It happened historically that the Russian version of the name of the
> city has already stuck in minds of the foreigners.
>
> Being a Ukrainian, I’d be more than happy to change it to Kyiv, but
> I’m afraid it won’t play a good game for us in terms of marketing.

Схоже обговорення також можна знайти на Quora: [Should we spell the city in the Ukraine "Kiev" or "Kyiv"? Why?](https://www.quora.com/Should-we-spell-the-city-in-the-Ukraine-Kiev-or-Kyiv-Why):

> Transliterations can do some damage to the 'authentic' spellings,
> particularly when there's a letter in the original that doesn't exist
> in the other language. In 2006, the US Board of Geographic Names (the
> group that tries to make sense of all this) approved Kyiv on the
> request of the Ukrainian government. Particular spellings are
> sometimes of political importance to governments (witness: Bombay is
> now Mumbai; Rangoon is now Yangon).

Ще один фрагмент дискусії:

> Kiev was the most common spelling in twentieth-century English (before
> 1850, Kiow, Kiou, and Kiovia were more common).

Цікава стаття вийшла в Business Insider з назвою [Is It Time For The West To Stop Calling It 'Kiev' And Start Calling It 'Kyiv'?](http://www.businessinsider.com/kiev-or-kyiv-2014-1), після того як читачі закидали редакцію листами проханнями використовувати офіційну назву. Основні тези російською можна почитати в статті [Слово Kyiv начинает вытеснять Kiev в мировом словоупотреблении](http://gazeta.ua/ru/articles/chistota-movlennya/_slovo-kyiv-nachinaet-vytesnyat-kiev-v-mirovom-slovoupotreblenii/541631).

Ще одна стаття називається [Kiev or Kyiv? Why is the question of what to call Ukraine’s capital so hard to answer?](http://calvertjournal.com/features/show/4927). Причина - теж листи українців:

> It is difficult to ignore passionate comments from some of our
> Ukrainian readers and contributors about the “incorrect” spelling of
> their capital city

Очевидно, що ЗМІ та бізнес-видання не зможуть довго ігнорувати офіційні правила за умови, коли вони отримують велику кількість зауважень та прохань вживати слово Kyiv. Очевидно, що це хороший спосіб поступової експансії "українського" варіанту.

Google Trends [демонструє](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=kyiv,kiev), що `Kiev` на разі шукають частіше, ніж `Kyiv`.

Окремо потрібно зазначити, що ще є сфера авіа перевезень, де також використовується значення Kiev. Щоб змінити це, потрібно пройти певну кількість процедур і, судячи з усього, є не тривіальною задачею. На жаль, я не досліджував цю тему більш глибоко, тому нехай експерти з авіації мене доповнять.

Насамкінець хочу порекомендувати проект [Транслітерація міст](http://translit.i.gov.ua/default.aspx), що переймається правильним написанням українських міст англійською мовою. Там, зокрема, можна знайти, що звичне багатьом написання `Vinnitsya` не є правильним з точки зору правил транслітерації, натомість потрібно писати `Vinnytsia`.

Answer (score 7):

Є російський варіант написання і український варіант написання. Це само по собі досить переконливо, що українці хочуть, щоби іноземці користувалися саме українським варіантом, і знали, як це вимовляти українською мовою, а не якоюсь іншою.

Це інерційні процеси (в нас досить важкий спадок), треба просто й надалі пояснювати людям дуже просто і на всіх рівнях: ваш варіант, "Kiev", - це російська мова, українською треба писати "Kyiv". На закиди щодо двомовності країни дуже легко відповісти, що: "в нас багатомовна країна, але державна мова в ній одна, то ж, будь ласка, поважайте нашу державну мову."

Answer (score 5):

***Пояснити*** (раз і назавжди) навряд чи можливо, але ***пояснювати*** можна і варто. Протягом останніх сторіч Україну в світі репрезентувала російська/радянська держава, тож природно, що вона розповсюдила саме російські варіанти вимови і написання Києва. Нам це не подобається, але такий вже узус склався в англійській мові - як ми звикли називати Paris "Парижем", хоча самі французи вимовляють "Парі́", так і англомовці звикли писати і вимовляти Kiev. Швидко це не зміниш. Але якщо ми ввічливо, але наполегливо будемо це роз'яснювати, за кілька років (може пару десятиріч) зміниться спочатку звичка, а там і літературна норма. Поки що можна пояснювати це своїм персональним друзям, мовляв, "мені так буде приємніше". Наприклад, я за кілька років перевчив своїх англомовних співбесідників називати мене Serhii, хоча спочатку вони намагалися називати мене більш поширеною російською версією Serghei. Ввічливість і наполегливість :)

Comment: чи варто витрачати сили саме на це?

Comment: @Chizh ввічливість і наполегливість не завжди вимагають багато сил, іноді вони просто стають приємною звичкою. Здебільшого це стається тоді, коли бачиш результати своєї діяльності.
В принципі, можна тиснути на державу, щоби вона цим щільніше займалася, але в цілому завжди краще просто мати свою позицію, що базується на конкретних знаннях, і провадити її доступними методами.